# Input validation inside for loop in Java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, validation

My program has an array called `answers` which holds 20 elements. I have a for loop that prompts the user to input either A, B, C, or D and then add that input to the array. I've been trying to use a while loop nested inside the for loop to check if the input is valid. If the input is anything other than A, B, C, or D, I want to prompt the user to put in a new answer and then check it again and only continue to the next element once the input is valid.

```
      String[] answers = new String[20];     //empty array for the student's answers
      String input;                          //keyboard input
      
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      
      //prompt user for input and check if it's valid
      //if it is, add input to the array
      for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
      {
         System.out.print("Enter your answer for problem #" + (i + 1) + ": ");
         input = keyboard.nextLine();
         
         while (input.equals("A") == false || input.equals("B") == false || input.equals("C") ==   false || input.equals("D") == false)
         {
            System.out.println("You must enter either A, B, C, or D.");
            System.out.print("Please reenter your answer for problem #" + (i + 1) + ": ");
            input = keyboard.nextLine();
         }
         answers[i] = input; 
      }
```

I decided to use string arrays because I don't know how to do it any other way, but I wonder if the issue comes misusing the .equals method in my while loop.

Every time I run the program it looks like this:

```
Enter your answer for problem #1: A
You must enter either A, B, C, or D.
Please reenter your answer for problem #1:
```

As you can see it prompts the user to reenter the answer even when the input was valid. I've been working at this for so long now and I still don't know how to fix it!

Comment: Think carefully about the condition in your while loop. Can it ever be false?

Answer (score 2):

Change your "or" logic to "and" logic.

Your while condition is always true because the input can only be one of the characters, but would have to be *all* of the characters (ie impossible) for the total condition to be true.

Also, this expression

```
input.equals("A") == false
```

Can (and should) be changed to

```
!input.equals("A")
```

to cut down on code clutter, making it easier to read.

So then, try

```
while (!input.equals("A") &&
  !input.equals("B") &&
  !input.equals("C") &&
  !input.equals("D")) {
```

---

btw, a simpler way of coding this is:

```
while (!input.matches("[ABCD]") {
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Now that you explained the logic it makes so much sense haha.